# Trouble with time attribute in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having this trouble in converting the exiting time string into a new Time object.

When I type this in console

```
t = Time.parse("8am")  
2010-12-06 08:00:00 +0530
```

it gives back `08:00` as result as seen above.

But when I store this value using

```
business.start_time = t
business.save(:validate => false)
```

it stores `02:30` in MySql db.

This happens only when I store via console. When the same data comes from forms, it stores correctly as `08:00` in MySQL table. Is there any problem here. The time zone is set different from the default utc. Please help. what should i do.

I have to parse through all the records in a table and take one string attribute and convert it into its equivalent Time class value and store it in another attribute in the same table. I am writing a rake task for it. But while storing, I get 02:30 instead 08:00 (for example).

Comment: So when you use "8am" in your app, you want it to mean 8am (UTC) rather than 8am (IST)?

Comment: What is output of business.start_time.utc and t.utc ?

Comment: business.start_time.utc gives 2000-01-01 02:30:00 UTC

Comment: I want to use plain ruby Time.parse in my console. I dont want to use rails custom Time.parse method. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be very careful with dates and MySQL. Datetime fields are stored as if they were strings in the db--so whatever Rails is sending in (check your log for the SQL) is what will be stored. I assume you're set to UTC in your environment.rb, so your Time object is being output in UTC as a string.

MySQL is poor (in my opinion) with respect to handling times in different zones and converting between zones.

I recommend you don't rush through your date handling. Always handle dates in your application and DB in UTC, and do any conversion to a specific timezone on a parsing (by specifying the timezone) or by formatting it in the view.

Answer (score 0):

The time seems to be stored in UTC. Try setting the timezone correctly when starting your console session.

Comment: I have set the timezone correctly to what I require. But still it stores it in UTC format. Can I not store the times in my prefered timezone format in the table ?